# Passing an updated variable to a label in a scene from rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a root view controller, which displays a score on a scene using an SKLabelNode. You can navigate from this root to a second view controller, where the score can change by playing a short game. When I pop back to the root view controller, the score doesn't update.

I've successfully connected both view controllers using a protocol/delegate, so the score is being passed from the second view controller to the root. **The issue is that there is a variable in the game scene of the root controller that won't update.**

I've tried doing this in the scene file (TheSceneIMade):

```
var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode! // this is a class variable

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // among other things in this function...
    scoreLabel = fgNode.childNode(withName: "score_number") as! SKLabelNode
}
```

The "didMove" is only called once b/c it's the root view controller, and everything else is popped on and popped off.

In the scene's view controller file, I did this:

```
var sceneExample: MyScene? // this is a class variable

override func viewDidLoad() {
    sceneExample = MyScene(fileNamed: "TheSceneIMade")
}
```

And then I've tried to change scoreLabel.text in viewWillAppear, but nothing is working.

How do I access and update the scene variable from its own view controller?

Comment: can you make sure that when you get back to your root view controller, your variable data is updated?

Comment: My guess is that you are updating a new instance of scene. I don't know your design, but if you change in static var scoreLabel, you can access in a single var that not depend on instance

Comment: Do you need 2 view controllers?  Perhaps your design is more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yeah, and it works. The whole set-up between the two allows me to pass the variable to the root view controller. The problem is that b/c it's the root, it only calls viewDidLoad once, and I can't seem to add the variable as a label to the scene that easily.

Comment: just because it works does not mean it is not needlessly complex.  Unless you plan on doing things outside of SpriteKit, there is no need for multiple VC's, and you may end up painting yourself into a corner if you do not carefully design your layout.  If you stuck to 1 VC and multiple scenes,  you could easily pass data from one scene to the next without having to worry about swapping VCs and other things that may hinder development.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Definitely a good point, but it's almost like an arcade. So I have one viewController that holds a scene with a fun little menu, and the rest of the viewControllers govern specific games, that are all totally different.

Comment: You can do the same with multiple scenes,  look into SKTransition to achieve the effects to make it appear like separate scenes are popping over the menu

Comment: @Knight0fDragon But if one game is chess and another is Scrabble, won't that get a little crazy in terms of the code specifying one particular type of game?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152549/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-illuminatedtype).